# How to use API chaining to create a contact and a relationship

Tags: api, chaining

I've read all the docs I could find, the code examples, the 4.6 explorer, but I'm not grasping one piece. Below is code to create a new adult contact (via profile submit, to get some extra validation for free), and multiple student contacts, each with a relationship to the adult. When chaining the relationship piece, what goes into contact_id_a and contact_id_b?

Here is the error result, calling code is at the bottom of this post:

```
Array
(
    [error] => Error in call to Profile_submit : Error in call to Relationship_create : contact_id_b is not a valid integer
    [error_code] => 2001
    [error_data] => Array
        (
            [error_field] => contact_id_b
            [type] => integer
            [error_code] => 2001
            [entity] => Profile
            [action] => submit
            [is_error] => 1
            [error_message] => Error in call to Profile_submit : Error in call to Relationship_create : contact_id_b is not a valid integer
        )

)
```

Edit: updated the code to better reflect what I'm trying to do, please see the comments on the innermost calls to create relationships:

```
  //build array of student details
  $student_profiles = array();
  foreach ($_POST['student_details'] AS $student_record){

    $student_profiles[] = array(
          'sequential'  => 1,
          'profile_id'  => 14,
          'first_name'  => $student_record['student_first_name'],
          'last_name'   => $student_record['student_last_name'],
          'gender_id'   =>  $student_record['gender_id'],
          'birth_date'  => $student_record['birth_date'],
          'allergies'   => $student_record['allergies'],
          'api.Relationship.create' => array (
                  'sequential' => 1,
                  'contact_id_a' => '$value.id',  //is this the valid contact ID of the student profile we just submitted?
                  'contact_id_b' => '$value.api.Profile.submit',  //how do i fix this to get the Profile.submit id from the parent's record?
                  'relationship_type_id' => 1,
                  'is_permission_a_b' => 0,
                  'is_permission_b_a' => 1,
                ),
         );
  }

    //build parent details and attach student detail array
    $parent_profile = array(
      'sequential' => 1,
      'profile_id' => 14,
      'first_name' => $'first_name',
      'last_name' => $'last_name',
      'api.Profile.submit' => $student_profiles,
    );

    //submit the main profile with all chained items
    try {
        $parent_result = civicrm_api3('Profile', 'submit', $parent_profile);
    }
    catch (CiviCRM_API3_Exception $e) {
      // handle error here
      $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
      $errorCode = $e->getErrorCode();
      $errorData = $e->getExtraParams();
      return array('error' => $errorMessage, 'error_code' => $errorCode, 'error_data' => $errorData);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it would be '$value.id' (ex. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/examples/Contact/APIChainedArrayValuesFromSiblingFunction.php). Basically, '$value' can be used to reference any values added by the parent api call.

Also, to your question about sanitization, the values should be sanitized. However, I would recommend using CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve() to get the submitted values from the request rather than $_POST as it does some extra sanitization work.

Comment: Agree with the suggestion that you use CR_Utils_Request::retrieve() rather than accessing the $_POST directly

Comment: So is $value context sensitive to the parent API call, or to the top-level API call? If I want to use the API to create 1 adult, chain 2 student records, and chain student/parent relationships within each student, do I keep using $value? My hope is to use a form with the jQuery Repeater plugin to do multiple student sign-ups in one form, and validate/submit the whole thing at once.