# Add relationship on profile submission

Tags: wordpress, profile, relationships

Currently there is no a way to add relationship to a profile on submission. Meaning when someone submits a new profile that a relationship be attached to that contact.

This question outlines how it can be done via API [How to use API chaining to create a contact and a relationship](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-to-use-api-chaining-to-create-a-contact-and-a-relationship)

In the case I currently need it for WP is the CMS, so I would be seeking something that is CMS independent, the Drupal modules wouldn't work.

What is needed to be done so that there is an option in the settings of the profile to create a relationship. Has anyone done any work like this or have any ideas on what makes sense to look at for something be developed?

Comment: Just a thought here ... is the Webform_CiviCRM _integration module code a helpful guide to doing this?

Answer (score 3):

There is a scenario where a relationship can be created via a profile. If you add a "Current Employer" field to a profile, the employer gets created or matched by name and an "Employee of" relationship is created between the individual and the employer.

If you need more flexibility, the [CiviRelate extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirelate) may help.

If this doesn't meet you needs, I would consider using the [Webform CiviCRM Integration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm), if that's feasible in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This would be using WP as the CMS, so these options wouldn't work. I am seeking something that is CMS independent.

Comment: Ah, I see you've edited the question to specify the CMS. Apologies for being Drupal-centric! I've added the tag wordpress to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Updating this to note that it can be done with the [Caldera Forms CiviCRM](https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm/) integration plugin.